# Markdown Value rendered "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, simplemde

I have some javascript code that gives this error when I added Simple Markdown

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
Code:
```

here is the code I implemented in application.js

```
var simplemde = new SimpleMDE({ spellChecker: false, element: $("#post_content")[0] });
```

The script in my layout:

```
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/simplemde/latest/simplemde.min.js"></script>
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Moste likely you create `SimpleMDE`  at a time where no element with the id `post_content` is in the DOM.

Comment: What can I do to rectify that. Can I do that `var simplemde = new SimpleMDE({ spellChecker: false, element: $("")[0] });`

Comment: Now I have that `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,`

Comment: Maybe you could create `SimpleMDE` in the same place (function) in which you create the `post_content` element and until then leave the `var simplemde;` undefined

Comment: @spickermann sorry I don't really know what can I do? Have you a tips to see what you  mean?